# How do i execute a command relative to player's torso rotation?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I know that that exists:

```
/execute at @p rotated as @p run particle minecraft:barrier ^ ^ ^3
```

but it uses head's rotation

Comment: Why do you need torso rotation?

Comment: To make cool particle wings and some more particle stuff

Answer (score 2):

Using armor stands and `data` command I was able to make it work.

Using this command to summon a armor stand with the tag `wings`:

```
summon minecraft:armor_stand ~ ~1 ~ {Marker:1b,Invisible:1b,Tags:[wings]}
```

It's `Invisible` and `Marker` so it can't be seen (except for spectators) nor interacted with (except with commands).

---

The first command would be to teleport the armor stand to the player:

```
tp @e[type=minecraft:armor_stand,nbt={Tags:[wings]}] SemlanBakelsen
```

---

The second command set's the vertical rotation of the armor stand to 0:

```
data modify entity @e[type=minecraft:armor_stand,nbt={Tags:[wings]},limit=1] Rotation[1] set value 0.0f
```

[image: Command chain]

---

Now you can use a command like this:

```
execute as @e[type=minecraft:armor_stand,nbt={Tags:[wings]}] at @s run tp @e[nbt={Tags:[wings2]}] ^ ^ ^3
```

In this case, the command executes as the armor stand at the player and teleports another armor stand relative to the first armor stand.

I used an additional command to teleport a third armor stand to the side, in the image you can see I am looking down but the armor stand in front of me is at the same level:
[image: armor stands]